# Mongoose populate option and query time

Tags: node.js, performance, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am working on a platform where I use mongoose .populate number of times in all my queries, I turn on the mongoose debug mode and find that there is hardly difference in query execution time (for 100 document now , there will will be 100000 doc in future) with using populate and without using populate.

I know that basically populate is also doing a finOne query internally , my question is, is using `.populate` will increase my query time or is it anyways going to effect my performance if number of record  reaches millions. Also is there any alternate that I can choose to increase performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you're correct - you want to avoid using populate() since it will issue another query for each row. Keep in mind that this is a full round-trip to the server. Mongo doesn't have any sort of concept for a join, so when you do populate you're issuing an additional query for each row in your returned set.

The technique to work around this is to denormalize your data - don't design a mongo database like a relational one. The mongo docs have lots of information on how to do this. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/ One important thing to keep in mind with Mongo design is that you never want to have a subdocument with unbounded growth. Due to the way mongo space allocation and paging works, this can cause severe performance problems, so if you're in a situation like this it's best to normalize.

Another very common technique is subdocument caching. This is where you take partial data from the "joined" collection and cache it on the collection you're querying. In this case, you're trading space for performance because you have duplicate data. Also, you'll have to make sure you keep the data updated whenever there's a change. With mongoose, it is easy to do this as a post-save hook on the model of the foreign collection.